# Toggle visibility using v-show or v-if in Vue while using a setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, toggle, loading

I am using Vue2. I have a form. When submit is clicked I want to show a "Loading" Div for X amount of time. After this X amount of time, I want to Load the Form again. In a nutshell, after a click, toggle visibility, after certain code is executed and waited certain time, toggle it again.

I have two Divs:

```
<div v-if="this.isHidden">
 LOADING....
</div>

<div v-if="!this.isHidden"> <!--or v-else -->
  <form @submit.prevent="">
  <!--Fields-->
  <button @click="updateProduct(product)" type="button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

On load, only "CONTENT" shows (isHidden = false).
When the method updateProduct() is executed I want the div "LOADING" to appear for X amount of seconds (isHidden=true) while "CONTENT" div must hide. Then after executing some code inside a setTimeout function, I want them to toggle once again (isHidden = false).

```
data: function() {
   return {
     //isHidden is initialized as false
     isHidden: false,
   };
},
```

My method looks like this:

```
updateProduct(product){
  this.isHidden = true;
  alert(this.isHidden + 'This correctly shows true. CONTENT correctly toggles and HIDES. LOADING also works correctly and APPEARS.');
  //I want to delay the following code with setTimeout so that I am able to control for how long I want to show LOADING
  setTimeout(function(){
    //do a bunch of tasks that work correctly... 
    axios.post('/api/product/' + product.id, data)
       .then(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
     }).catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);            
     });

    //After all my code is executed, I am still inside the setTimeout function inside the updateProduct method so now i do this:
    this.isHidden = false;
    alert(this.isHidden + ' This correctly shows false BUT DIVS DO NOT UPDATE ANYMORE, I am stuck with the LOADING div');
   //although my code works fine and the alert shows the correct value for isHidden, my view is stuck in LOADING

  }, 2000);
}
```

I have attempted to move this.isHidden = false; outside of the setTimeout function but it still doesn't "toggle" the visibility.

I have also tried to use v-if instead of v-show, same  behaviour.

Comment: `axios.post` is asynchronous so `this.isHidden = false;` is executed before the post happens - don't use `alert` for debugging as it blocks code execution so the results may be inaccurate ... but the main problem is `this` ... it's not the right `this` inside the setTimeout callback ... use `setTimeout(() => {` ... or `setTimeout(function(){ ... etc ... }.bind(this), 2000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is `this` inside the setTimeout callback

Because you use `function() {}` it's NOT what you want `this` to be

Either use arrow notation `setTimeout(() => {}, 2000)`

```
updateProduct(product) {
  this.isHidden = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    //do a bunch of tasks that work correctly... 
    axios.post('/api/product/' + product.id, data)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    this.isHidden = false;
  }, 2000);
}
```

Or, if arrow notation scares you `setTimeout(function() {}.bind(this), 2000)`

```
updateProduct(product) {
  this.isHidden = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    //do a bunch of tasks that work correctly... 
    axios.post('/api/product/' + product.id, data)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    this.isHidden = false;
  }.bind(this), 2000);
}
```

As a side note, do not use `alert` for debugging - it blocks execution of javascript and can lead to unreliable debugging results

Comment: The Arrow Notation did the magic, thanks for the thorough explanation and alternatives!

Answer (score -1):

Just Use V-else

```html
<div v-if="!this.isHidden"> <!--or v-else -->
  <form @submit.prevent="">
  <!--Fields-->
  <button @click="updateProduct(product)" type="button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div v-else>
<div v-if="this.isHidden">
 LOADING....
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it won't fix `this` in the `setTimeout`

Comment: you aren't addressing the issue